# How can I tame VirtualBox's CPU usage when running Silverlight-based web site in IE under Windows?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a client who uses another vendor for their point of sale system. I need to periodically download reports from this system and currently the only way to do so is with Internet Explorer and it uses Silverlight. So I run Windows under VirtualBox, and this works, but after a few minutes, Windows slows to a crawl. It will take literally a full minute for a click or keypress to register.

When I look at the CPU usage, VirtualBox is using more than 200% of the CPU (2.9 GHz Quad-Core i7). Closing the IE window (and waiting a minute for the clicking of the close button to register) returns things to normal.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: I'm tempted to say this would be a better fit for Super User, as really it's a Windows question… "Why is an obsolete app framework, running on an obsolete browser, using too much in the way of resources?"

Comment: I'll try posting it there. It's such an odd combination of technologies, I wasn't sure of the best place.

Comment: I admit it's a tough call, but both those platforms are pretty much end of life, so behaviour on a modern OS is going to be a bit unpredictable. 200% of a quad core is presumably because the Win instance is running full-tilt on a 2-core-allocated VM, but the diagnosis of that feels like it's in the Windows camp.